# Firebug Show Totally Different Styles to Inspector

Tags: firebug, inspector

Firebug is totally bugging me out.
I love all the extra features like Firediff and Colour picker.
But it just doesn't show the CSS that Inspector does.

I click on exactly the same div tag, which I need Inspector to find for me, then the rules (from my custom css) just don't show, nada.

So I have to go back to Inspector.
Any thoughts?

Either how I should be using Firebug. Or addons for FF Inspect to give it the same func.

Answer (score 0):

Please [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/entry), and include any error messages from the error console (Ctrl+Shift+J/Cmd+Shift+J) and which Firebug extensions you are using.

Comment: It's probably me but each time I open Firebug it opens on a diff screen, sometimes with the Style pane hidden, which I don't know how to get back, sometimes on DOM or other panel. It seems to happen when I navigate to another tab and come back.

Comment: But sometimes it opens right. With my the CSS properly visible. MOstly it defaults to all the "inherited from" view. Not ideal.

Comment: Yeah, those look like bugs/conflicts in Firediff/some Firebug other extension. As said, please file a bug and provide enough information so we can take a look at it.